# The exponent of self-adjoint operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

If $X$ is a Hilbert space and $A$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator on $X$, is it necessarily that $A^k$ is self-adjoint for all positive integer $k$? (I have already known that the conclusion holds for $k$ a power of $2$)

Answer (score 4):

By the functional calculus for selfadjoint operators, $f(A)$ is selfadjoint for any finite real-valued measurable function $f$; see, for example, K. Yosida, Functional Analysis, Springer, 1965.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This follows immediately from the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) and form the [functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Borel_functional_calculus)
of selfadjoint operators, even for a much wider range of functions.